# How to run requestAnimationFrame() synchronously?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

So I'm making a small tetris like game where tiles fall on each other, get destroyed etc. I'm making HTML5 canvas animation through `requestAnimationFrame()`. This method is called to gather tiles hanging in mid-air and drop them down smoothly:

```
function dropTiles() {
    var tileArray = getFallingTiles();
    function step() {
        var finished = true;
        for (var index = 0; index < tileArray.length; ++index) {
            var currentTile = tileArray[index];
            if (currentTile.fallDepth > 0) {
                finished = false;
                currentTile.erase();
                currentTile.positionY -= 1;
                currentTile.fallDepth -= 1;
                currentTile.draw();
            }
        }
        if (!finished) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

This is the main method where the above method is called from:

```
function doGameEvents() {
    setCanvasListeners(false);
    do {
        var comboFactor = 1;
        dropTiles();
        while (getGroups()) {
            score();
            dropTiles();
            ++comboFactor;
        }
        if (comboFactor == 1) {
            var newTile = getRandomTile();
            TILES.push(newTile);
            dropTiles();
        }
    } while (!hasMoves());
    setCanvasListeners(true);
}
```

Everything works okay but I noticed that once `dropTiles()` is called the control gets immediately transferred to the next instruction, even if the latter is not yet finished (i.e. `score()` is called with tiles still hanging in mid-air).

So my question is: how to make `requestAnimationFrame()` synchronous and completely finish before the control exits my `dropTiles()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. You rewrite your drop method to *notify* you when it is done. At its simplest:

```
function dropTiles(callback) {
    //...
    function step() {
        //...
        if (!finished) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
        else
        {
            if(callback)callback();
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

So now when you call `drop`, you can

```
drop(function(){
    //this code runs when drop is finished
});
```

If you need to wait for many `drop`s to finish, you might choose to use [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) instead. (hint: Promises are here to stay... you should really learn how to use them).

```
function dropTiles() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        //...
        function step() {
            //...
            if (!finished) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            }
            else
            {
                resolve();
            }
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    });
}
```

Now you can:

```
drop().then(function(){
    //drop is finished
});
```

or

```
Promise.all([drop(), drop(), drop()]).then(function(){
    //all the drops finished
});
```